# Android Fragment, static variables not initialized on "new"?

Tags: android-fragments, initialization

I keep getting some old Data in a Fragment that I basically want to have built itself up from Scratch.
It's driving me nuts ;)

Here are the relevant code bits:  In activity, when Fragment is created:

```
        ...
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "remoteFrag is NOT available");

        // Create fragment
        int savePos=mDataManager.getPosition();
        mDataManager.setPosition(position);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        remoteFrag = new RemoteFragment();
        args.putSerializable(ExtraXMLParser, mDataManager);
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "mDataManager is " + ((mDataManager == null)? "not ":"") + "set");
        remoteFrag.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, remoteFrag);
        if(mDataManager.getPosition()!=savePos)
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
        ...
```

What do I want to achieve: In the activity, that I want to relaunch (basically, the App behaves different if I am in a local Wifi network, Menu is different and different Options are available.  A splash screen probes for this type of environment and initializes the DataManager appropriately).

```
        ...
        Log.w(LOG_TAG,"terminating...");
        leaveRemoteView();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.remove(remoteFrag);
        remoteFrag=null;
        mDataManager=null;
        Intent intent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        ...
```

In the remoteFrag I have:

```
public class RemoteFragment extends Fragment implements DataManager.ProcessXMLData  {
RemoteDetail remoteBottom = null;
private View thisView;
private ViewGroup thisContainer;
static private DataManager _dataManager = null;
static private boolean _dataManagerRegistered = false;

final private static String LOG_TAG = "RemoteFragment";


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
    // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
    // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "creating RemoteFragment");
    if(_dataManager == null) {
        try {
            _dataManager = (DataManager) getArguments().getSerializable(RemoteDisplay.ExtraXMLParser);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            _dataManager = null;
            Log.e(LOG_TAG , "mXmlParser not passed as arguments");
        }
    }
    else
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "dataManager was not null");
    thisContainer = container;
    ...
```

If I force the app to restart with the second bit of code above, and I make the Fragment launch with the first and third section, I receive the following LogCat:

```
03-21 14:32:37.930: D/ViewRootImpl(12915): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
03-21 14:32:38.090: D/RemoteDisplay(12915): selection is 0
03-21 14:32:38.090: W/RemoteDisplay(12915): remoteFrag is NOT available
03-21 14:32:38.090: W/RemoteDisplay(12915): mDataManager is set
03-21 14:32:38.110: W/RemoteFragment(12915): creating RemoteFragment
03-21 14:32:38.110: D/RemoteFragment(12915): dataManager was not null
03-21 14:32:38.110: D/RemoteFragment(12915): will inflate now...
03-21 14:32:38.130: D/RemoteFragment(12915): finshed create view
```

The confusing message that messes everything up is "dataManager was not null".
This means the fragment did not try to receive the variable _dataManager from the activity passed as argument, and the initialization on the top of the class is overwritten somewhere before OnCreateView is called with an old value.

Where and what can I do to avoid this?  The only way I managed to behave the fragment as I want is to completely remove the App from the recent activities.

Sorry if this turned out to be somewhat long... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found one quite obvious solution.
I just add an additional custom constructor for the Fragment that initializes my variables:

```
    RemoteFragment() {
    _dataManager=null;
    _dataManagerRegistered = false;
}
```

I am still a bit puzzled why this is not done with the custom constructor.